# Javascript regex match skipping back to back new line

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, match

So I have this string:

```
function abc() {\n\n    return def;\n}
```

And I use this:

```
string.match(/[^\r\n]+/g)
```

And it matches into 3 lines:

Match 1: function abc() {

Match 2: return def;

Match 3: }

But it is missing a fourth match which should be the new line with no characters after the '{'.

I am using the website https://regex101.com/r/ALvFIN/1/ to test.

Set to flavor: ECMAScript

Regex: /[^\r\n]+/g

Test String:

```
function abc() {

    return def;
}
```

Any idea how to correctly match the double \n\n with no characters on line 2? I have tried the whitespace \s and \S but not right. Starting to think I need to look at an alternative solution.

Comment: Why do you expect it to capture a `\n`? The regex specifically matches anything  that _isn't_ a `\n`. What's the goal of this regex anyway? To split a string into its lines?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/eiGccO/1

Comment: Or if that *really* is all you want to do- why not just split the string on `\n`?
`string.split('\n')`

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68410228/3832970) with a couple of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to match a string of one or more non-linebreak chars or an empty line.

This logic means you simply want to *split a string with a single line break sequence*.

To match ASCII line breaks, CRLF, LF or CR, you can use `/\r\n?|\n/`.

To match any Unicode line break sequence, you can use `/\r\n|[\r\n\f\u000b\u0085\u2028\u2029]/`.

```js
console.log("function abc() {\n\n    return def;\n}".split(/\r\n?|\n/))

// Any Unicode line break sequence:
var rx = /\r\n|[\r\n\f\u000b\u0085\u2028\u2029]/;
console.log("function abc() {\n\n    return def;\n}".split(rx))
```

And if you still want to use `.match()` simply add a `^$` alternative to your regex with `/m` flag to make `^` and `$` match start/end of a line:

```js
console.log("function abc() {\n\n    return def;\n}".match(/[^\r\n]+|^$/gm))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the string into its constituent lines, you can use this: `/^.*$/gm`. Note the `m` option to enable multiline matching.